# Cannot switch user - Error Code: 1

Tags: 16.04, su

I'm in an interesting situation where I'm trying to log in to my headless Ubuntu instance in the cloud and I cannot switch to one of my users.

Here's what I'm trying:

`login_id@cloud_machine:~> su webhost
Password: 
(ERROR)-(Exit Code 1)-(General error)`

I don't get any additional information and I'm certain I've used the correct password.  If I had to guess what's wrong, it was that I'd tried to install gitlab earlier, but I've since removed it and undone any installation steps I can think of.  I can still switch to my other users, so it's definitely something with this user.

I've already removed that user's .bashrc file to avoid any log-in weirdness.

Any ideas what else to try?  Any files I can overwrite that run when I switch users?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the user had it's shell set to `/bin/false`.

If you're seeing the same thing I am, the answer is in this thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39314/su-does-not-change-user-but-does-not-respond-with-an-error-either

Apologies for the noise.